# oAuth 2 Gmail - Android /iOS connexion and server use

Tags: java, android, ios, oauth-2.0

Since a few days it seems that our Android and iOS apps are no longer able to connect using oAuth.
Indeed we get a 403 "disallowed_useragent" error.

It seems that the use of a "Web application" Client ID is blocked from these applications.
Yet on the Android version we are using a WebView.

After reading https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html :

- Should one necessarily use "Google sign-in"?
- Does an "Android" client ID have "offline_access" permission?
- We would like Android / iOS / web to use the same "ID Client", can we on Android and iOS change the userAgent?

Thank you in advance.

Cordially.

Answer (score 1):

In Android:

Try the following code to fix the oAuth 2 Gmail connection failure issue in Android

```
mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 Google");
```

In IOS:

Try the following code to fix the oAuth 2 Gmail connection failure issue in IOS

Objective C:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36", @"UserAgent", nil];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

Swift 3.0:

```
let dictionaty = NSDictionary(object: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36", forKey: "UserAgent" as NSCopying)
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: dictionaty)
```

Or The another way is to add the below code in your config.xml file

```
<preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value"Mozilla/5.0 Google" />
```

For the brief information about that user agents refer the link: https://mobiforge.com/research-analysis/webviews-and-user-agent-strings